# how to send mail with image in windows service

Tags: c#, email, windows-services

i have one windows service to send mail periodically.
i am using following code to embed image in mail 
 LinkedResource imagelink = new LinkedResource(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Images/header.png"), "image/png");

this is not working in windows service.

please suggest anyone if any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Services do not use the proper relative path with mappath. Try using

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Images/header.png"
```

as your path and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext is only available when being hosted by IIS.  A windows service is basically like a console application without a console.

I would use:

```
... = new LinkedResource(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Images/header.png"),
        "image/png");
```